# CSS Grids correct alignment

Tags: html, angularjs, css, ionic-framework

[image]
Trying to realize the above structure in my UI. A big picture and thumbnails below it.
I am using the [grid components](http://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#grid) for it. Code:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col">
        <img url="bigPic"></img>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col" ng-repeat="pic in Pics">
        <img url="pic"></img>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now I want to delete pictures out of `Pics`. That's why I introduce badges with the following code:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col">
        <img url="bigPic"></img>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col" ng-repeat="pic in Pics">
        <img url="pic"></img>
        <span class="badge badge-assertive picture-thumbnail-badge"
                                  on-tap="removePic($index)">
            <i class="icon ion-ios7-close-empty"></i>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

And this results in the following (with a css class moving the badges in the top left corner):

```
.picture-thumbnail-badge{
  position: relative;
  top:-60px;
  right:65px;
  z-index: 100;
}
```

[image]
The Problem here is that the thumbnails are no longer centered underneath the big picture. I guess the flexbox is taking into account the size of the badge somehow.
My obvious question now: how can I ignore the badge in the alignment calculation and make this thumbnail row centered, even with badges?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: try `position:absolute;` instead of `position:relative;` on `.picture-thumbnail-badge`

Comment: this works (when the `top` and `bottom` values are adjusted)! thank you. Give a proper answer and I'll vote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move the `.picture-thumbnail-badge` out  of the flow. For that, you can use [`position:absolute;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#Absolute_positioning) instead of `position:relative;` :

```
.picture-thumbnail-badge{
  position: absolute;
  top:-60px;
  right:65px;
  z-index: 100;
}
```

*(note that the parent needs to be positioned  with `position:relative;`)*